# How do I retrieve all values from a 3D range and insert into the current worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a series of worksheets named `1.. 50`. I want the values of the 3D range `'1:50'!A10` inserted into a range on the current worksheet, `RawData`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `offset` to achieve this. In column `A` of `RawData` insert a list of 1 through 50. In column `B` you can use the following formula: `=Offset(char(39) & $A1 & char(39) & "!A10")`. Copying this down column `B` will give you the result in Cell `A10` of each sheet 1 through 50.

Alternate VBA solution if sheets aren't sequential:

```
Sub getA10()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim writeRow As Integer

    writeRow = 1

    'iterate through all the sheets in the workbook
    For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        'Don't capture A10 of RawData
        If sht.Name <> "RawData" Then

            'Write in Column A the sheet name, and in column B the Value in A10
            Sheets("RawData").Cells(writeRow, 1).Value = sht.Name
            Sheets("RawData").Cells(writeRow, 2).Value = sht.Range("A10").Value

            'increment the row
            writeRow = writeRow + 1
        End If
    Next sht
End Sub
```

Comment: So basically Column A contains the name of the worksheet and we're concatenating? How would you approach this if the names are less consistent in format and not sequential?

Comment: Three ways: 1) VBA (I just edited answer to include this solution)  2)You could make a named range for the `A10` cell in each sheet that is sequential and use offset 3)You could manually type in the sheet name to Column `A` of your `RawData` sheet. None of them are particularly fast. I would, personally, go with VBA since it could scale without having to muck around with manual lists or named ranges.

Comment: Initially, I thought VBA was the answer but I was hoping built-in formulae would be able to help. I'll probably just go with VBA for this. Thanks!